# Seeking links to free GIS university courses

Tags: references

Does anyone know of any free Study resources for GIS, cartography or Photogrammetry from recognized universities?

Answer (score 1):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

Introduction to Geospatial Technology (Course)

https://www.nterlearning.org/web/guest/course-details?cid=2501

```
Geographic Information Systems
Understanding Geospatial Data Models
Understanding Coordinate Systems and Map Projections
Displaying Geospatial Data
Creating Geospatial Data
Understanding Remote Sensing and Aerial Photography
Basic Geospatial Analysis Techniques
```

https://www.nterlearning.org/web/guest/course-details?cid=2502

```
Reviewing the Basics of Geospatial Data
Introduction to Geospatial Analysis
Using Attribute and Spatial Queries for Data Exploration
Vector Data Analysis Overlay Techniques
Vector Data Analysis Creating a Site Selection Model
Vector Data Analysis Network Analysis
Raster Data Analysis Working with Topographic Data
Raster Data Analysis Density Surfaces
```

Compatible with Quantum GIS (QGIS)

http://qgis.org/en/site/

---

Penn State University offers many of their courses for free on the web see http://open.ems.psu.edu/courseware. (Scroll down to geography).

---

GITTA is developed by Swiss universities and offers all lessons for free (you have to subscribe to a newsletter).

From the [GITTA website](http://www.gitta.info):

> GITTA (Geographic Information Technology Training Alliance) is a
> platform offering e-learning content as Open Educational Resources
> (OER). A pool of over 40 e-learning lessons covers the following
> thematic areas: GI Systems, Data Capture, Data Management, Spatial
> Modeling, Spatial Analysis, and Cartographic Presentation. Content is
> in large parts multi-lingual, with English, German, and French
> materials.

---

OSGeo have started to put together a GIS training resource: [ICA-OSGeo Labs initiative](http://www.geoforall.org/)

> Mission - "Making geospatial education and opportunities accessible to
> all"

Not sure it currently counts as a GIS university course yet, but it certainly is being built by contributors that include university departments.